# GetEmail() Null in Google Login with Firebase using Kotlin

Tags: firebase, kotlin, firebase-authentication, google-signin

First of all, sorry if there is already a post that resolves my problem, but the ones that I found didnt solve it.

Im creating a login with email and pass (that works fine) plus the login with google, the login works but neither in Firebase console nor in the code with 'account.email' can I see the email.

[Firebase Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6OOK0.png)

```
binding.btGoogle.setOnClickListener() {
            val googleConfig: GoogleSignInOptions =
                GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                    .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.default_web_client_id)).build()
            val googleClient: GoogleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, googleConfig)
            googleClient.signOut()
            startActivityForResult(googleClient.signInIntent, GOOGLE_SIGN_IN)
        }
```

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)

        if (requestCode == GOOGLE_SIGN_IN) {
            val task: Task<GoogleSignInAccount> = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data)
            try {
                val account: GoogleSignInAccount? = task.getResult(ApiException::class.java)
//here 'account.email' is already null
                if (account != null) {
                    val credential: AuthCredential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(
                        account.idToken,
                        null
                    )

                    FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signInWithCredential(credential).addOnCompleteListener() {
                            if (it.isSuccessful) {
                                showHome(account.email ?: "", ProviderType.GOOGLE)
                            } else {
                                showAlert()
                            }
                        }
                }
            } catch (e: ApiException) {
                showAlert()
            }
        }
    }
```

Debugging, I can see other attributes like displayName, givenName, idToken... but email is just null.

Solutions I tryed:

- Both with the option on and off from Firebase "Avoid creating multiple accounts with the same e-mail"
- Using 'account.email' or 'getEmail()'

Something that bothers me:

- Looking for answers I saw that some people mentioned that they
  accepted read permisions, I did not saw any pop up asking me to do
  it.

Its my first question in stackoverflow plus my English is not the best... Sorry if i did something wrong and thank you in advance.

Comment: Once SO allow, mark your answer as accepted - this is the proper way of making question answered on SO

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski I think you corrected some of my text, thank you, and yea ill mark it as answered

Comment: Yep, I did. You can always review the changes made to any post by clicking "edited" which will show you all the revisions plus some controls if you are the OP of edited post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Omfg I'm just so stupid, I missed one word :)

I had this:

```
val googleConfig: GoogleSignInOptions =
                GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
        .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))
        .build()
```

And I needed this:

```
val googleConfig: GoogleSignInOptions =
                GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
        .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))
        .requestEmail()
        .build()
```

Comment: Man, you really saved my time. +1 to you